# Using matplotlib boxplot with groupby

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by, boxplot

I have what superficially appears to be a simple question, but I cannot find the answer.  I have a feature in my df for which I would like to use groupby on two different categories.   Here's my metacode:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['Col1', 'Col2'] )
# Assume each series below repeats.  
df['X'] = pd.Series(['A','B','A','B',...,'A','B','A','B'])
df['Y'] = pd.Series(['X','Y','X','Y',...,'X','Y','X','Y'])
```

How can I use groupby to create 4 box plotsfor a particular feature in the df?  (Eg, keys {'A','X'},{'B','X'},{'A','Y'},{'B','Y'}) for the each data series?   I can do the following:

```
df['Col1'].groupby([df.X,df.Y]).describe()
```

...what's the analogy for box plot?

Comment: As written you'll only ever get 2 combinations ( (A,X) and (B,Y) ).  But as for those, did you look at the documentation for boxplot?  What's wrong with `df.boxplot(column='Col1', by=['X', 'Y'])`?

Comment: @Ajean - Sorry, assume the series for 'X' and 'Y' are random.   Good spot. I'l try your suggestion.

Comment: @Ajean - That worked....thanks from a newbie!  :-)